# How to create a relative symbolic link for a file

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a link to a JS file. If I type `ln -s ./script.js ./scriptLink` it successfully creates a working link. But If I type `ln -s ./script.js ../scriptLink`, the link that's created has red `X` and an orange lock on the icon.

When I type `ls -l` in the parent directory, I get

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 alex alex   11 July 30 11:38  scriptLink -> ./script.js`

and `scriptLink` and `./script.js` are red. I also tried creating the link with `sudo`, but the result is the same. Changing the `script.js` permissions to 777 also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inform the ln command that the link you are creating is a relative type, like this:

```
ln -s ./script.js -r ../scriptLink
```